# Server.Transfer() in SharePoint OR any equal alternative to that?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages, data, exception

In my SharePoint solution, I want to transfer from one application page to another application page, both located in the same folder in file system like below:

```
/MySiteCollection/_layouts/15/Business/Order/orderforms/orderconfirmation.aspx
```

I am trying `Server.Transfer("/MySiteCollection/_layouts/15/Business/Order/orderforms/orderconfirmation.aspx")` under button click event, but getting this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

InnerException: {"The file /MySiteCollection/_layouts/15/Business/Order/orderforms/orderconfirmation.aspx does not exist.":null}
```

If Server.Transfer() did not support in sharepoint, then I am looking for any alternative to this that can perform the same thing?

Comment: try to use SPUtility.Redirect. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.redirect.aspx

Comment: Ok, But SPUtility.Redirect redirects to different page (orderconfirmation.aspx) but I want the same page (source page) should remained in browser's address bar like we can using Server.Transfer() in asp.net, Is that possible in sharepoint?

Comment: check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645235/sharepoint-server-transfer also try to server.execute